# Define a path (custom direction) for particles of an emitter

Tags: qt, qtquick2, particles

I'm using Qt5.3 and I'm using QtQuick.Particles2.0 system to show fluid motion inside a pipe by an emitter and defining a direction. For a straight line of pipe, I have no problem to show the particles inside the pipe (since it's just a target position). But consider I have deviated pipe; How can I define a path for the particles in the emitter? (see the photo)

[image: The photo is for illustrative purpose]

Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody have any hint or idea? Or other solutions for showing fluid flow?